# WebStorm V8 Profiling : (Stacktrace cut)?

Tags: node.js, profiling, webstorm, v8

I am trying to profile a Node.js application in JetBrains WebStorm, only to find that there is a "Stacktrace cut" message that makes it impossible to see useful weight of the different function calls.

Can anyone point me towards a solution for this problem?

[image: error screenshot]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What **Node.js** version do you use? Is it **8.5+** by chance? looks similar to [WEB-28735](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-28735) that is fixed in upcoming webStorm 2017.3

Comment: Thinkpad-Pro:dendro joaorocha$ node --version
v8.6.0

Comment: it must be the same issue then; please try updating to [2017.3 EAP](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/WI/WebStorm+EAP)